# Getting KeyError: 9 with Python, Copy of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to loop through a DataFrame in google colab and it's been working so far, but I ran into an issue. I created a copy of a dataframe, removed the rows that had NaN in the column of interest, and the loop is no longer working. I am getting KeyError: 9.

```
def findJobsCertAnn(thresholdYear):
  jobCount = 0
  for i in range(jobsDFCopy.shape[0]):
    if (thresholdYear - 1) < jobsDFCopy['Years Since Approval'][i] <= thresholdYear:
        jobCount += jobsDFCopy['Certified Jobs'][i]
  return jobCount
```

This should return the number of jobs in the column, but only columns that have a value in "Years Since Approval" between certain bounds. For the 'Threshold Year', I use the numbers 1 through 9, though I feel that is irrelevant.

What's weird is that it works correctly in the original DataFrame, not the copy.
This is where it works:

```
def findCompCertAnn(threshold):
  rowNum = 0
  for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if (threshold - 1) < df['Years Since Approval'][i] <= threshold:
      rowNum += 1
  return rowNum
```

The expected result here is to return the number of rows with a value in the column 'Years Since Approval' that are within the bounds stated, just the same as before. I get no key error here.

I'm not sure what the issue is but I'm guessing it is in how I copied the DataFrame.
Here is how I copied the DataFrame:

```
jobsDFCopy = df.copy()

jobsDFCopy.dropna(subset=['Certified Jobs'], inplace=True)
```

It removes the rows that have 'NaN' in the column 'Certified Jobs'.

I have tried accessing and comparing (using if statements) and looping through values in JobsDFCopy just to see if it works, and it does, but it does not when I try to do it in this function.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the full error from Colab:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:

6 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 9

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 9
```

Comment: Remember that the syntax you're using is fetching by KEY, not by row number.  When you `dropna`, the keys are not renumbered, so you now have gaps.  Perhaps you want `iloc` instead.  Have you printed your `jobsDFCopy` to see what it actually looks like?

Comment: Or simply run call `reset_index()` after `dropna()`, but in that case you'll have to remove `inplace=True` option and return a value.

Comment: The issue is that the row index does not match the shape of the `df`.  Using `.iloc` will work, but you could also do `for index, row in jobsDFCopy.iterrows():` instead of `for i in range(jobsDFCopy.shape[0]):` and access row values with `row['Years Since Approval']` instead of `jobsDFCopy['Years Since Approval'][i]`

Comment: @TimRoberts, I did print JobsDFCopy and it looks identical to the original df.
In response to everyone, I will try to use iloc, I just have not used it before. Will update with results.

Comment: I ended up doing what NotAName suggested and it worked. Thanks guys!